# Does an exiled Aetherling come back into play untapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I attack with [Aetherling](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aetherling). After it deals damage I blink it out. When it returns at my end step, does it come back untapped and ready to block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, when Aetherling returns to the battlefield, it's considered a new permanent, so it enters the battlefield without remembering that it was tapped.

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.
>   There are seven exceptions to this rule:

(*none of the exceptions apply here*).

Comment: Note that this _is_ still affected by effects that indicate how permanents enter the battlefield; if your opponent controls a card like Urabrask or Blind Obedience which says that 'creatures [your opponents control] enter the battlefield tapped' then Aetherling will enter play tapped when coming out of exile and not just when played from your hand.